# C: strtof returns 0.000, what´s wrong?

Tags: c

I´m having some troubles with this part of my C code. Everything should work well except a function "strtof", which returns 0.000 instead of a float number.

What the code should do:
read a line, e.g. "a 12"
if the first character is "a", than, using strtof, it should set pointer to next white space and save value between the two white spaces to x... (probably wrong)

(All libraries are included and MAX_LINE is defined.)

Thank you for any answer :).

```
int run(void) {

    char line[MAX_LINE];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);          

    char * ptr;
    ptr = strtok (line," ");                

    if (strcmp(ptr, "a") == 0){
        {
            float x;

            x = strtof(line, &ptr);          /*HERE*/
            printf("%f", x);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the first strtok loop for ? Ir does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I forgot to delete it... no, it actually doesnt :) (it was an older version of the code..)

Comment: If the first character is an `a`, then you are calling strtof on the string "a ...", and that doesn't look much like a float, so strtof returns 0.000.  If you want to get the string after the a, call strtof where the first argument points to the next token, not the beginning of the line.

Comment: Try adding `if((ptr=strtok(NULL," ")))` just before `x = strtof(line, &ptr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [float strtof (const char* str, char** endptr);](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)
if your first char is 'a' then you should call :

```
x = strtof(line+2,&ptr);
```

if `line` is used with no offset, strtof will parse "a 12" and stop at 'a', you could have check the `ptr` value to see where the parsing stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You don't read the floating value after the "a", i think you need to do this:

```
ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
x = strtof(ptr, NULL);
```

The next call of `strtok` will read the "12" and the `strtof`will convert it to a float into the x variable.

Answer (score 1):

You already pointed it out:

> What the code should do: read a line, e.g. "a 12" if the first character is "a", than, using strtof, it should set pointer to next white space and save value between the two white spaces to x... (probably wrong)

From the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Floats.html) (strtod and strtof are equivalent):

> If the string is empty, contains only whitespace, or **does not contain an initial substring that has the expected syntax for a floating-point number**, no conversion is performed. In this case, strtod returns a value of zero and the value returned in *tailptr is the value of string.